# Spark read.jdbc saveAsTable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got an error while saveAsTable.
Here is my code

```
val df = spark.read.jdbc(url,table,"id",0,100000000,4,properties)
df.write.saveAsTable("custom_order_1kw")
```

"custoom_order_1kw" is a table in Mysql, which is 700+MB.

Error log:

```
WARN spark.HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 10 with no recent heartbeats: 166323 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
17/04/12 15:55:15 ERROR scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 10 on 172.21.102.93: Executor heartbeat timed out after 166323 ms
17/04/12 15:55:15 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 172.21.102.93): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 166323 ms
17/04/12 15:55:25 ERROR scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 10 on 172.21.102.93: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
```

After 4 same errors occured, the task is aborted.

I use spark-shell to test code.

```
spark-shell --master spark://172.21.102.93:7077 --executor-memory 4g --driver-cores 1 --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 8g
```

If I select a smaller table to extract (200+MB), All things right!

Any idea on what's the error?

Comment: Looks like executor is not able to start ..may be because insufficient memory? which mode of spark you are running this job in? if local, does you machine have more than 12gigs?

Comment: spark is running on local mode. My machine has over 20g memory

Answer (score 0):

> spark-defaults.conf
>   Set the spark.network.timeout to a higher value default is 120

You can add same in command also

```
spark-submit --conf spark.network.timeout 10000000 --class myclass.neuralnet.TrainNetSpark --master spark://master.cluster:7077 --driver-memory 30G --executor-memory 14G --num-executors 7 --executor-cores 8 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000 path/to/my.jar
```